# Read message with a consumer connected to an existing bus

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm trying to understand how to connect consumers to an existing bus like explained [here](https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/message-consumers.html#connecting-to-an-existing-bus), but I don't understand how this thing should work

my code:

```
public interface IMessage
{
    string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
        {
            var host = sbc.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });
        });

        bus.Start();

        bus.ConnectConsumer<TestConsumer>();

        bus.Publish<IMessage>(new { Text = "Hi" });

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();

        bus.Stop();
    }
}

public class TestConsumer : IConsumer<IMessage>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IMessage> context)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received: {context.Message.Text}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I don't understand where the message is sent since aren't there any queue specified, and therefore I don't know how the message can be consumed.

Is there a way to specify on what queue the message will be sent and written OUTSIDE the bus definition?

What am I missing?

Comment: The docs that you have referred to explain that you can only connect to the temp queue and the temp queue has a limited set of uses.

Answer (score 0):

What you are publishing here

```
bus.Publish(new { Text = "Hi" });
```

is an anonymous type, not IMessage to which you are subscribed, i think you need to create IMessage interface, then create some class implementing IMessage and send over the bus

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
bus.ConnectConsumer<TestConsumer>();
```

Consider using:

```
sbc.ReceiveEndpoint("queue-name", e => e.Consumer<TestConsumer>());
```

That will create a queue named "queue-name" and connect your consumer to it.

If you need to connect a receive endpoint to the bus after the fact, you can use:

```
host.ConnectReceiveEndpoint("queue-name", e => e.Consumer<TestConsumer>());
```

You'll need to save the host from the configuration, but it will allow you to add the receive endpoint after the bus is started.

Answer (score 0):

The docs you linked state that published messages are not received by the temporary queue and it has a limited set of use cases.

As far as I understand there's a distinction between senders and consumers in Mass Transit.

Senders send messages to an **exchange** not to queues.
Consumers are responsible for creating a queue and binding this queue to an exchange. The queue-exchange binding is done auto-magically based on the type of the message.

For this reason it's important that your consumers are created first. If the a message is sent without a consumer having created a queue the message has nowhere to go and will be lost.